# Python: Round time to the nearest second and minute

Tags: python, time, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` with a column `Timestamp` where each values are the number of seconds since midnight with nanosecond precision. For example:

```
Timestamp
34200.984537482
34201.395432198
```

and so on. 34200 seconds since midnight is 9:30:00am.

I would like to create new entries in my `dataframe` with one column `Second` and `Minute` where I round the `Timestamp` to its nearest second and minute (forward looking). So

```
Timestamp         Second           Minute
34200.984537482   34201            34260
34201.395432198   34202            34260
```

How can I do this in Python? Also, should I use Pandas' `DateTimeIndex`? Once I round the time, I will compute the time difference between each timestamps so maybe DateTimeIndex is more appropriate.

Comment: You should definitely use datetime64/DatetimeIndex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Series [round](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html) method:

```
In [11]: df.Timestamp.round()
Out[11]: 
0    34201
1    34201
Name: Timestamp, dtype: float64

In [12]: df.Timestamp.round(1)
Out[12]: 
0    34201.0
1    34201.4
Name: Timestamp, dtype: float64

In [13]: df.Timestamp.round(-1)
Out[13]: 
0    34200
1    34200
Name: Timestamp, dtype: float64
```

I recommend using datetime64 or DatetimeIndex rather than as seconds from midnight... keeping time is **hard**.

One simple way to get a proper datetime column:

```
In [21]: pd.Timestamp('2014-03-04') + df.Timestamp.apply(pd.offsets.Second)
Out[21]: 
0   2014-03-04 09:30:00
1   2014-03-04 09:30:01
Name: Timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks Andy. `df.Timestamp.round()` works well. For a proper datetime column, do I need to have the date? If I just want the time that should be fine no? Can I use `pd.offsets.Second` (or Minute) to round to the desired forward time?

Comment: @CharlesM I think you're best off with a date, of course you could use a dummy one if it didn't matter. you *may* be able to use timedelta, I don't *think* there is a pandas time (without date) object you can use...

Answer (score 2):

For the nearest second, just use the `math.ceil`, so:

```
    import math
    second = math.ceil(timestamp)
```

For the nearest minute, divide by 60.0, round that, then multiply by 60.